# Cannot modify or add or remove the userInfo of payload in notification service extension in iOS10

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios10, serviceextension

In the short period of notification service extension's

```
- (void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent * _Nonnull))contentHandler
```

I can modify the **UNMutableNotificationContent** properties except the userInfo. Taking a mutuablecopy of **userInfo** dictionary and altering and setting it back again is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

**Swift 4:**

```swift
bestAttemptContent?.userInfo.updateValue("someValue", forKey: "someKey")
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any documentation about this. But for me it didn't work out when I tried to set my custom type as a value for a certain kvp in userInfo dictionary. Regular strings works just fine:

```swift
// works fine with an enum string raw value.
bestAttemptContent.userInfo["myEnumVariable"] = MyEnum.someCase.rawValue

// doesn't work.
// Only shows raw push, ignoring all changes done via notification extension.
bestAttemptContent.userInfo["myEnumVariable"] = MyEnum.someCase
```